# Azure Devops - PS Scripts

Tags: powershell, azure-devops

I was trying to run below PS Inline script thru Azure devops Pipeline. But iam getting error on agent log
Pipeline code:

```
trigger:

master
pool:
name: 'Dev1'

steps:

task: PowerShell@2
inputs:
targetType: 'inline'
script: |
    # Write your PowerShell commands here.

    New-Item -Path "C:\Manoj" -Force
```

Error on Agent:

```
Starting: PowerShell
Task : PowerShell
Description : Run a PowerShell script on Linux, macOS, or Windows
Version : 2.165.0
Author : Microsoft Corporation
Help : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell
Generating script.
========================== Starting Command Output ===========================
"C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -NoLogo -NoProfile -NonInteractive -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -Command ". 'C:\tmp\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.165.2_work_temp\65dd1488-c132-4b9a-8403-0604d37f43a4.ps1'"
New-Item : Access to the path 'C:\Manoj' is denied.
At C:\tmp\vsts-agent-win-x64-2.165.2_work_temp\65dd1488-c132-4b9a-8403-0604d37f43a4.ps1:4 char:1

New-Item -Path "C:\Manoj" -Force
  + CategoryInfo          : PermissionDenied: (C:\Manoj:String) [New-Item], UnauthorizedAccessException
  + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NewItemUnauthorizedAccessError,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.NewItemCommand

##[error]PowerShell exited with code '1'.
Finishing: PowerShell
```

Comment: The error indicates an access issue. Did you investigate in that direction?

Answer (score 0):

Using a Microsoft hosted agent, the code worked for me.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - '*'

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
        New-Item -Path "C:\Manoj" -Force
```

If you're using a self-hosted agent, verify the user account running the azure devops service meets your permissions requirements.

Answer (score 0):

The error shows that account under which azdo agent run has no permissions to create objects in a root of system drive. Such restriction sounds logical since agent supposed to serve in multi-user/multi-project scenario.

Therefore, consider to build a logic of a pipeline scoped only within a working directory.
For instance: `Pipeline.Workspace`

```yaml
trigger:
  master

pool:
  name: 'Dev1'

steps:
- task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: inline
    script: |
        New-Item -Path "$(Pipeline.Workspace)\Manoj" -Force
```

In this case artifacts of different pipelines are isolated from each other.

Reference: [Use predefined variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using self-hosted agent, try to add the agent service user an admin (or at least disk writer) privileges, or allow it to write for the folder.